# How to compare 2 fields in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 fields on my Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   min= models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
   max= models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

How to compare if max is gte to min them when I click save or register?

I am aware of Django Form's clean but I don't know how to use it to compare two fields.

**EDIT**

Thank you for suggesting your answers. However, I cant see the returned message.

I can see the message on postal code but not on the min and max

```
def clean_postal_code(self, *args, **kwargs):
    postal_code = self.cleaned_data.get("postal_code")
    if not postal_code.isdigit():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please Enter a number")
    return postal_code

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    min = cleaned_data.get("min")
    max = cleaned_data.get("max")
    if max < min:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Max Salary should be greater than Min Salary!")
    return cleaned_data
```

template:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<!-- Error messaging -->
<div id="errors">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>There were some errors in the information you entered. Please correct the following:</p>
        <ul>
            {% for field in form%}
                {% if field.errors %}<li>{{ field.label }}: {{ field.errors|striptags }}</li>{% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Error messaging -->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Do you need to compare fields on the client or on the server side?

Comment: server side so that I can use validation error

Comment: How do you *render* the form in the template? Can you share the relevant part of the template?

Answer (score 2):

To [validate fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) you should implement the forms `clean` method:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        min = cleaned_data.get("min")
        max = cleaned_data.get("max")
        if max < min:
            raise ValidationError("max should be greater than or equal to min!")
        return cleaned_data
```

Since this error is not for a specific field it would be present in `form.non_field_errors`. You can either simply render it `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` or you can loop over it:

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    {{ error }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It now stops the saving but I cant see the error message on return.

Comment: @rodjames The error is caught by the form. You won't be able to see it unless you render the forms errors. This would be a non-field error, ensure that you render `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` in the template.

Comment: @rodjames check my edit on how to render the error.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `clean` to validate this for a `ModelForm` and/or `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModel(models.Model):
    min = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    max = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.min is not None and self.max is not None and self.min > self.max:
            raise ValidationError('Min should be less than or equal to max')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

We can furthermore enforce this on the database level, if the database supports checks with Django's [*constraint framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import F, Q

class MyModel(models.Model):
    min = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    max = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.min is not None and self.max is not None and self.min > self.max:
            raise ValidationError('Min should be less than or equal to max')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                ~Q(min__gt=F('max')),
                name='min_lte_max'
            )
        ]
```

By checking this at the model layer, it means that model forms and model admins that work with this instance will call clean, so there is no need to implement this on the form layer.

If we work with a database constraint, and the database supports this feature, it makes it impossible to store a record in the database where `min` is greater than `max`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement clean method on the form

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    min_value = cleaned_data.get("min")
    max_value= cleaned_data.get("max")

    if min_value is not None and max_value is not None:
        if min_value > max_value:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Min value should be less than Max value"
            )
```

To show Validation errors raised from clean method in template you need to iterate over {{ form.non_field_errors }}

Alternatively you can use self.add_error, to attach error to the specific field. [django form - raising specific field validation error from clean()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574484/django-form-raising-specific-field-validation-error-from-clean)